# Cast pointer to member function to intptr_t

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, member-functions

The question: Is there a way to cast pointer to member function to intptr_t in C++?

Known factors:

1. I know member function pointer is very special one
2. I know that member function passes hidden "this" parameter (__thiscall).
3. I know that sizeof(member function pointer) > sizeof(intptr_t) in some cases, 
   in this question I'm only talking about the case where it is possible, i.e. in my case sizeof(member function pointer) == sizeof(intptr_t).
4. And finally I know that casting pointers to intptr_t isn't a good pattern.

Sample code:

```
class test // No inheritance, in the case I need
    {
    public:
    void func();    // No virtual, or any special modifiers in the case I need
    };

void main2()
    {
    intptr_t p = &test::func;
    };
```

I know a workaround to do this cast, but I don't like it, since it requeres a temp variable:

```
void my_way()
    {
    intptr_t p;
    auto t = &test::func;       // Temp variable, I don't like the fact I need to use it, but I have no other way for now
    p = *reinterpret_cast<intptr_t*>(&t);
    };
```

So the question is how to do the trick inline as an rvalue expression, with no temp variable (and no memcpy which is the same).

Example:

```
reinterpret_cast<??>(???_cast<??>(???_cast<??>( &test::func )))
```

(I don't care about how beautiful the expression will be).

-------------------------( below some thoughts about why, not the question )--------------------------------

There are some simmilar themes on this site, but all of them mostly speaking about "why you do so?", or "why do you need this?", and speaking about this solves the problem for the one who askes, but not for me.

Why do I need this staff: I'm writing some kind of task where I've decided to implement my own mechanism for dynamic linking. 
There can be several specific applications.

In my case - dynamic linkage mechanism - I want to pass a pointer to function to another module.
I have a class and an interface as a separate structure (I know, there are libs with the same approach).
All the classes using this mechanism are known to be plain (no inheritance at all, so no virtuals and etc).
All this runs on x86 32 bit, or at most on 64 Windows, compiled by MSVC 2012.
As interface is completely isolated from class it uses an array of pointers.
Lib passes the array to the host process.
And in the host process I have this... It's not even a "problem", but still:

```
inline int my_interface::func_name(int param)
    {
    decltype(&interface_name::func_name) temp;
    *((intptr_t*)&temp) = reinterpret_cast<interface_name::funcs*>(interface_desc->funcs)->func_name;
    return (reinterpret_cast<decltype(this)>(object)->*temp)(param);
    };
```

It's an inline function, so I want it to be as small as possible, and if it is possible I'd like to eliminate "temp", because I'm not sure if the compiler will correctly eliminate this, even with all optimizations.

Other applications (hypotetic): 
- What if i want to protect the memory page where my member function resides with a specific guard. 
WinAPI gives me a way to do so, but it needs address of the page.
There is no problem to do this for normal function, but for member - only with WA I described? Or there is a way?
- What if I want to patch the image in runtime? I.e. to find some const and replace it with another?
There can be at least several reasons for runtime patching: 2.1 dynamic linkage relocation process, 2.2 code obfuscation.

This is just for a note - readers often ask "what for", I don't want to discuss why, because in my opinion there can be many applications, all of them not for newbie, but more for security guys etc...

I herebly ask not to discuss "Why do so?", "Why don't use existing mechanism for dll/boost/other libs/other languages?" in this thread.

Comment: Note that there's an extra factor: whether sizeof(mfp) == sizeof(intptr_t) will depend on the compiler you're using, not just the types. See if your compiler accepts an intermediate cast to `(void*)`, but you're on your own as far as correctness is concerned.

Comment: It can't be done via casting: Pointer-to-members can only be cast to other pointer-to-members, even with `reinterpret_cast`. Unfortunately, there's nothing to quote, because the Standard does only specify which casts *are* allowed. You could, however, use a "memcpy" of the pointer-to-member (that is, copy the contents of the pointer-to-member by using a pointer to pointer-to-member).

Comment: Given your own point #4, can you explain *why* you want to do this anyway? For instance, are you trying to find a way to create a generic container for mfps to arbitrary objects?

Comment: Extended explanation "why".

Comment: To DyP:
The thing is - I don't wanna this inline to insert additional "memcpy" everywhere in code, the same trick is done by my WA,
but it's a useless instruction - I don't need a copy, I just need a "reinterpretation of bits"...

Comment: (If you [put an `@` before a user name in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), the user will be notified. The creator of a question/answer will always be notified.) An alternative to using `memcpy` is to use a `union`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2f4cc8214a897a2) *Note:* That's undefined behaviour, so better look up what it does in your compiler's documentation. (Probably it's ok.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the spec does not allow you to cast function pointers or member pointers to intptr_t.  The reason for this is because you may need more than one intptr_t's worth of data to describe them.  For example, member pointers on gcc are 3 intptr_t's long, and MSCVs range from 1 to 4 intptr_t's long.  Much of this is used to handle virtual functions.

On some old hardware (that C++ supports), pointers are also actually smaller than function pointers.  This happens on small systems where you may only need to point to an 8-bit memory structure, but programs get loaded into a 16-bit program memory space.

Much of the time, this pattern you are trying to use is used to create delegates: member function pointers permanently tied to a specific object.  This can be done with 2 int pointers and a wrapping function

```
struct Delegate
{
    intptr_t   obj;  // I'll use intptr_t here, but often this is void*
    intptr_t   func;
};

// you need one of these for each type of mfp you use
static void callT_Test(intptr_t obj)
{
    T* realObj = reinterpret_cast<T*>(obj);
    realObj->test();
}

// constructing a delegate to call test on t
Delegate d;
d.obj = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&t);
d.func = &callT_Test;
```

Comment: Thanks for direct answer.

Comment: I think the same way, but I can't leave the problem, till I find a prove.
Thing that eats me is: if it's impossible, then C++ tries to forbid me to access the address of binary image of a function.
I.e. the place where the code resides in memory.

Comment: More accurately, C++ provides no officially sanctioned way to access the binary image of a function.  If it provided an officially sanctioned way to do it, then it would limit the use of C++ to platforms which meet the requirements of that officially sanctioned method.  As an example, some of those embedded platforms DO actually forbid accessing the binary image of the code (they are called Harvard Architectures).

Now, if you are willing to get your hands dirty, and be compiler and platform specific, there are compiler specific ways to do what you want.

Comment: For example, here is a link to a great article trying to make fast delegates by decomposing member function pointers in compiler specific ways.  These are the kinds of things you are talking about doing.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

Comment: Disagree with you. You argument would be legitimate only if there were no way to cast plain function to int, but there is - you just reinterpret_cast it. This means C++ do allow you to get pointer to "binary image of code", only pointer to class member is forbidden for some unknown reason. Sorry for necroposting.